# Create method like createCriteria().list(){} in Groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy, closures

I want to create a method that has multi params when I call that method need to create a closure to call that method.

For example in Grails we have:

```
 User.createCriteria().list(){}
```

I want to create a method like list.

Comment: Please share an example call to that type of method

Comment: def item(t1,t2){println(t1)}
new Example().item(){}

Comment: @ErnestKiwele def item(t1,t2){println(t1)}
new Example().item(){t1=2}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to declare a method that takes a closure as parameter. If the last parameter in the list is a closure, then it can be invoked in that fashion:

```
def doSomething(int arg1, int arg2, Closure arg3) {
    arg3(arg1, arg2)
}
```

And you can invoke either as:

```
doSomething(3, 5) {a,b -> a + b}
```

Or as:

```
doSomething(3, 5, {a,b -> a + b})
```

The method can also have no other argument but the closure:

```
def doSomething(Closure arg3) {
    arg3()
}

print doSomething {println "closure invoked"}
print doSomething() {println "closure invoked"}
```

More information can be found on the [closure documentation page](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html).